# Serde JSON deserializing enums

Tags: json, rust, enums, serde

I have an enum:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Action {
    Join,
    Leave,
}
```

and a struct:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Message {
    action: Action,
}
```

and I pass a JSON string:

```rust
"{\"action\":0}" // `json_string` var
```

but when I try deserialzing this like this:

```rust
let msg: Message = serde_json::from_str(json_string)?;
```

I get the error `expected value at line 1 column 11`.

In the JSON if I were to replace the number `0` with the string `"Join"` it works, but I want the number to correspond to the `Action` enum's values (`0` is `Action::Join`, `1` is `Action::Leave`) since its coming from a TypeScript request. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Try this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6b578ddfa3e64da3ce6e1838f878bd85

Comment: You can also add an match statement if needed so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`serde_repr`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_repr)!

Here's example code from the library's README:

```rust
use serde_repr::{Serialize_repr, Deserialize_repr};

#[derive(Serialize_repr, Deserialize_repr, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[repr(u8)]
enum SmallPrime {
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
    Five = 5,
    Seven = 7,
}

fn main() -> serde_json::Result<()> {
    let j = serde_json::to_string(&SmallPrime::Seven)?;
    assert_eq!(j, "7");

    let p: SmallPrime = serde_json::from_str("2")?;
    assert_eq!(p, SmallPrime::Two);

    Ok(())
}
```

For your case:

```rust
use serde_repr::{Serialize_repr, Deserialize_repr};

#[derive(Serialize_repr, Deserialize_repr)]
#[repr(u8)]
enum Action {
    Join = 0,
    Leave = 1,
}

use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Message {
    action: Action,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without adding any extra dependencies, the least verbose way is possibly to use "my favourite serde trick", the `try_from` and `into` [container attributes](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#try_from). But in this case I feel that custom implementations of `Deserialize` and `Serialize` are more appropriate:

```rust
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Action {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        match i8::deserialize(deserializer)? {
            0 => Ok(Action::Join),
            1 => Ok(Action::Leave),
            _ => Err(serde::de::Error::custom("Expected 0 or 1 for action")),
        }
    }
}
impl Serialize for Action {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer,
    {
        serializer.serialize_i8(match self {
            Action::Join => 0,
            Action::Leave => 1,
        })
    }
}
```

The custom implementations only redirect to serializing/deserializing `i8`. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f71d42e02ea14b98a84432c08ac6dc4a)

Comment: Sweet that's a great option thanks!

Comment: Doesn't deserialize go into recursive call?

Comment: @Voilin No: `<Action as Deserialize>::deserialize` calls `<i8 as Deserialize>::deserialize`. Accordingly, the playground terminates. (I'm not sure why I didn't  do it consistently between serializer and deserializer, I could have just as well used `0i8.serialize(serializer)` (on the other hand, `deserializer.deserialize_i8()` would have required implementing a visitor. Nope.))